# How do i split string into 4 columns in ms sql?

Tags: sql-server, split

Example string: " s:6:"module";s:11:"leadCapture"; "
--Note: s is not important.

I tried using `string_split`:

```
SELECT value 
into temp
FROM STRING_SPLIT('s:6:"module";s:11:"leadCapture";s:6:"action";s:5:"save2";', ';');

select * from temp;
```

Below is the output:

```
Row 1: s:6:"module"
Row 2: s:11:"leadCapture"
Row 3: s:6:"action"
Row 4: s:5:"save2"
```

Expected Output:

```
6 - column 1, 
module - column 2, 
11 - column 3, 
leadcapture - column 4.
```

Comment: Which version of SQL Server engine do you use, precisely? The answer depends on that.

Comment: Or you could ask Marketo to provide data in a sane, standard format instead of [PHP serialize() format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php). If your data supplier won't cooperate then you'd be better off creating a PHP script that uses [unserialize()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) to read that and convert it to a more usable CSV, JSON or XML format.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will work starting with MS SQL Server 2016:

```sql
declare @s nvarchar(max) = N's:6:"module";s:11:"leadCapture";s:6:"action";s:5:"save2";';

select row_number() over(order by r.Ordinal, v.[key]) as [RN],
    v.value as [SubStringValue]
from (
    select t.[key] as [Ordinal], t.value as [Value]
    from openjson('["' + replace(string_escape(@s, 'json'), ';', '","') + '"]', '$') t
    where t.[key] <= 1
) r
    cross apply openjson('["' + replace(string_escape(r.Value, 'json'), ':', '","') + '"]', '$') v
where v.[key] > 0
order by RN;
```

Ugly and convoluted, but **at the time of writing** this is your only option if you want to do it in pure SQL in an on-prem instance. The alternatives are:

- Azure SQL (both SQL Database and Managed Instance) have an improved version of the `string_split()` function, which accepts an additional parameter, `enable_ordinal`. This will add an extra column into its output containing ordinal position of substrings within a string. If you use Azure version of SQL, or somehow have SQL Server 2022, this will allow you to avoid having to deal with JSON.
- CLR function. Pretty much the best solution when it comes to string manipulation in SQL Server, but can be a pain to maintain.
- Cleansing by some ETL tool (SSIS, ADF, AirFlow, whatever) before the data enters the database.